# Connecting to a Server, sending a string and receiving an object - BufferedReader not 'ready'?

Tags: java, networking

The server:

```
    public Server() {
    gui = new GUI();
    try {
        socket = new ServerSocket(2000);
        while (true) {
            Socket client = socket.accept();
            gui.append("Client accepted.");
            if (inetAddrFound(client.getInetAddress().getHostName())) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new IncomingClient(client));
                threads.put(client, thread);
                thread.start();
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class IncomingClient implements Runnable {

    BufferedReader reader;
    Socket sock;

    public IncomingClient(Socket socket) {
        gui.append("Incoming socket class instantiated.");
        try {
            this.sock = socket;
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            for (StackTraceElement s : e.getStackTrace()) {
                gui.append(s.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while (true) {
                gui.append("Trying to see if reader.readLine == null");
                if (!reader.ready()) {
                    System.out.println("Reader is not ready.");
                    continue;
                }
                if ((message = reader.readLine()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Reader is not null.");
                    System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                    gui.append(message);
                    if (idFound(message)) {
                        ObjectOutputStream stream = (ObjectOutputStream) sock.getOutputStream();
                        stream.writeObject(spooker);
                        stream.close();
                        threads.get(sock).interrupt();
                        threads.remove(sock);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The client:

```
private void connect() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(decode(ADDR), Integer.parseInt(decode(PORT)));
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writer.println(String.valueOf(encode(getMotherboardSN())));
        writer.flush;
        writer.close;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class IncomingSpookerObject implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SpookerObject object;
        try {
            while ((object = (SpookerObject) ois.readObject()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                spooker = (SpookerObject) ois.readObject();
                thread.interrupt();
                System.out.println(spooker.getX());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My aim is to connect to the server, send the user cpu id (unique identifier for each computer) to the server (cpu id is a string), the server will read the cpu id and if the user is registered (e.g. if their cpu id is on the database) then it will send them an object back (the Spooker object).

The spooker object is a test object which just holds int x = 4 and a method returning x, getX().

The reason I'm trying to do this is to help stop the software from being leaked. In the future, the spooker object will contain information to start the client software (e.g. the GUI size, the gui title, strings values etc.). This is to make the software harder to leak as it connects to the server and retrieves specific information back.

I hope I've been as clear as possible.

Archie

EDIT - updated server object.

Server output -

> Client accepted.
>   Incoming socket class instantiated.
>   Trying to see if reader.readLine == null
>
> Reader is not ready.
>   Reader is not ready.
>   Reader is not ready.
>   Reader is not ready.
>   Reader is not ready.
>   Reader is not ready.

It prints this out continuously - why is the reader never ready?

EDIT;
Added:

> writer.println writer.flush(); writer.close();

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Are you getting an error?  Have you debugged it?

Comment: @SteveSmith it seems that the client is connecting to the server, but this code `(message = reader.readLine()) != null` is either returning null or simply not running - since the `gui.append(message)` doesn't run.

Just debugged. It goes all the way and then reader.readLine is null.

Comment: It could be that the server is trying to read the data before the client has sent it.  Try getting the server to wait until `reader.ready()`.

Comment: @SteveSmith added, but the output is still the same.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the IncomingSpookerObject class

Comment: You need to wait until it is ready.  At the moment you're checking if it's ready and then dropping out if it's not.

Comment: @SteveSmith I changed it to continue.

Comment: @MauricePerry the IncomingClient class is used to wait until the server receives the clients "message", and then the server replies. 
The SpookerObject class will hold a lot of values / strings that will be used to create the client GUI - without them (e.g. if the user CPUID isn't found on the database) the client GUI won't be created and therefore the client will not be able to use the product.

Comment: Try changing `writer.write` to `writer.println`.

Comment: Still did not work. The BufferedReader is never ready.

Comment: @Archie what do you expect to happen when the cpu id is not recognized by the server?

Comment: @SteveSmith He doesn't need to wait until it's ready. `readLine()` will already block until there is a complete line. The `ready()` loop is literally a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending a CR with the client data, so as far as the server is concerned there is no full line to read yet.  Try changing `writer.write()` to `writer.println()`.

Comment: Changed - but still it doesn't read the line. It appears the BufferedReader is never ready.

Comment: He *is* sending a line terminator with the client data. He is calling `println()`, which does exactly that.

Comment: He is now, but he wasn't when I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. I had to use,
object = ois.readObject();
object instanceof

Not 
ois.readObject instanceOf

etc.

Sorry for the short answer, busy.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this solved the problem.  `instanceof` isn't used anywhere?

Comment: @SteveSmith in the updated version it is.

I got rid of the while loop and just used object = ois.readObject(). It seemed to work perfectly - and closing the socket at the end.

Answer (score -1):

The server is trying to read a line that's never ended. In your connect method, you should close the output stream.

UPDATE

Here an example that works. In fact, the output stream must not be closed because it would close the underlying socket.

Server:

```
public class Server {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int port = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 2000;
    try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            while (true) {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client accepted.");
                Thread thread = new Thread(new IncomingClient(client));
                thread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class IncomingClient implements Runnable {
        private final Socket sock;
        private final SpookerObject spooker = new SpookerObject();

        public IncomingClient(Socket socket) {
            System.out.println("Incoming socket class instantiated.");
            this.sock = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(istream);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(ostream)) {
                String message = in.readLine();
                if (message != null && idFound(message)) {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
                            && sock.isConnected()) {
                        System.out.println("Reader is not null.");
                        System.out.println("Message = " + message);
                        out.writeObject(spooker);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    sock.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean idFound(String id) {
            return "abcdef".equals(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client implements Closeable {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());

    private final Socket socket;
    private final ObjectInputStream ois;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress server = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            String cpuId = args[2];
            try (Client client = new Client(server, port, cpuId)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    System.out.println(client.readSpooker());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public Client(InetAddress address, int port, String cpuId)
            throws IOException {
        boolean ok = false;
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        try {
            OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
            out.println(cpuId);
            out.flush();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ok = true;
        } finally {
            if (!ok) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    public SpookerObject readSpooker() throws IOException {
        try {
            return (SpookerObject)ois.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new IOException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would prevent any more data being sent/received, like the object data.

Comment: OK, so do at least a println as @SteveSmith wrote

Comment: The problem is still not fixed. The bufferedreader is never ready.

Comment: OK, then remove the test on reader.ready(). What's its purpose anyway?

Comment: ` Socket.isConnected()` doesn't magically become false when the peer disconnects. You can't mix line and object I/O on the same socket. Your claim that this code works is hard to believe.

Comment: @EJP This condition (sock,isConnected()) is probably useless, you're right about that. If the connection is closed by the peer, the writeObject will throw an exception, and the thread will terminate. It works, but of course, I'm not asking you to believe anything.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `ready()` test and the `continue`. There is no point to it. You're just spin-looping until at least one byte is available to be read without blocking, and then you're quite probably blocking in `readLine()` anyway, as it blocks until an entire line is available to be read.

You also need to decide whether you're sending lines or objects. You can't do both via the same socket.

Comment: I disagree: the server reads lines from the input stream, and write objects on the output stream. There is nothing wrong with that.